# DC Motor driving large offset mass, smooth acceleration/deceleration?

Tags: control, brushless-dc-motor, stepper-motor, brushed-dc-motor

I've got a large mass (0.5-2kg) on the end of a 0.5m rod. I'm trying to swing it smoothly as an inverted pendulum using some brushed DC motors with planetary gearboxes and quadrature encoders (GoBILDA 5204 Series with a 117 RPM max. velocity, 1,425.1 counts per output shaft revolution and a 50.9:1 gear reduction), but I've found it impossible to speed up and slow down smoothly, below a certain commanded velocity (around 20 RPM) the motors stop suddenly and it causes a lot of vibration which makes my load cell readings incredibly noisy, and the rod can begin to move in sudden jerky steps, causing even more vibration. I'm led to believe this is an issue with many brushed DC motors that they operate poorly at very low velocity, but I'm also wondering if the controller (RoboClaw 2x15A) is to blame.

I'm wondering if a brushless motor such as a Maxon EC would be able to perform smooth acceleration and deceleration with sinusoidal commutation, or if I should consider a stepper motor with microstepping instead. Exact positioning of the pendulum is not critical since I am using the load cells as a control signal.

Comment: What are you using for feedback? No encoder? Just a load cell?

Comment: @DKNguyen the motors are under velocity PI control with quadrature encoders as feedback, but the velocity signal itself is from a PID using the load cells as feedback, so it's a two layer cascaded design.

Comment: What's the resolution on those encoders, gear ratio, and how slow is slow?

Comment: @DKNguyen added info to main question.

Comment: I would be leaning towards commutation in that case. You can't move the encoder to the input shaft can you? If you can, that would be a quickish way to check if the issue is sensor resolution.

Comment: @DKNguyen I think considering the decimal point in the datasheet, it is on the input shaft to the gearbox, indeed it appears to be mounted on the rear of the motor.

Comment: Oh, then that should be plenty of encoder resolution.

Comment: You could try a higher pole brushed motor too if it's easy and cheap to fit in to see if stability increases at lower speed. How does the motor turn under no-load a 20RPM. But if it's stiction, I am not sure what to do about that except lubricate.

Comment: I'd first be balancing the offset mass, or even overbalancing it to turn the inverted pendulum into a true one (as in a metronome).

Comment: @user_1818839 I can't unfortunately, as the offset mass has an important function in the design.